# No criteria match with filtered pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code to filter two pivot tables during a Physical Inventory count to compare count results with previous inventory data in a specific binaisle location.  It works great except when there is no count data for a specific location.  Then it lists everything in the table.  How do I code it to show no data in the table instead of all the data?

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

Set pt = Worksheets("Dbl Chk").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("iblc_binaisle")
NewCat = Worksheets("Dbl Chk").Range("B2").Value

On Error Resume Next

With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With


Set pt1 = Worksheets("Dbl Chk").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
Set Field1 = pt1.PivotFields("iblt_binaisle")

On Error Resume Next

With pt1
Field1.ClearAllFilters
Field1.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested because I didn't have any Pivot Table handy, but I think this should work. You may need to double check the syntax for selecting blanks in a pivot field. This should also negate the need for `On Error Resume Next`. Only use that if you absolutely **HAVE** to ... and even then double check if there is a way to avoid it :). If you do use it, make sure you set `On Error GoTo 0` right after you want to by-pass errors.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable, Field As PivotField, NewCat As String, pItem As PivotItem, bFound As Boolean

    Set pt = Worksheets("Dbl Chk").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set Field = pt.PivotFields("iblc_binaisle")
    NewCat = Worksheets("Dbl Chk").Range("B2").Value

    bFound = False
    For Each pItem In Field.PivotItems

        If pItem.Value = NewCat Then
            bFound = True
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    With Field
        .ClearAllFilters
        If bFound Then .CurrentPage = NewCat Else: .CurrentPage = "<>" 'i think this is syntax for blanks
    End With

    pt.RefreshTable
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for your help - sorry it took so long to get back to this - I ran the routine and got a run-time error 1004 at this point: Field.CurrentPage = NewCat Else - any other suggestions?

Comment: see my edited code and try again. I adjusted the `With Field` block.